# Extreme points and directions

Tags: extremal-graph-theory

> Consider the space $S$ defined by $S:=\{ (x,y) \mid 2x+y=2,~x,y \geq 0 \}$.
>
> Find the extreme points and the extreme direction of $S$.

I found that there are two extreme points : $(1,0)$ and $(0,2)$.

But I am stuck for the extreme directions, I don't know how to see graphically the extreme directions for this space $S$.

Comment: Unless I'm reading this wrong, this is just a simple line?

Comment: Yes, $S$ is a segment delimited by the points $(1,0)$ and $(0,2)$.

Comment: OK, so I'm not sure what your question is?

Comment: I need to find the extreme directions of $S$.

Comment: OK, I'm sorry, but I don't understand what that means.